# What is the recommended way to handle large textfields using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textfield

The twitter bootstrap (3 and 4) documentation is pretty clear on how to handle a lot of different form input types. However, it lacks information on the recommended way to have an element for a "large" text input field. For example to type an email or letter in (preferably with a maximum character count).

What is the recommended way to handle this in bootstrap or in "modern" HTML/CSS in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `input field`. I would recommend you use `textarea`

**Example**

```
<textarea class="form-control">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies.
    </textarea>
```

You can use jQuery to resize the `textarea` while typing.
**jQuery**

```
$("textarea").height( $("textarea")[0].scrollHeight );
```

**Css**

```
textarea {
width: 300px;
```

}

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsJRm/)

Comment: Is this responsive though? I guess I should just use min-width and max-width for that?

Comment: If your using bootstrap of course it should responsive `<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>` But if your not using bootstrap then you should use `min-width` and `max-width`

Comment: Alright, thanks! I really should find a good book/text about the inner workings of CSS, to clear stuff out a bit. It's mostly the layout part, and how it chooses sizes, which I find confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the HTML `<textarea>` element. This can be used with Bootstrap like any other input element. Wrap it in a `form-group` container and add the class `form-control` to the textarea itself.

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrjoPz)

Unfortunately, the textarea element does not accept a `maxlength` argument like input fields. To use a maximum character count to need to handle this with javascript.